# How to have breakpoints in XCode4 work not once, but always - without restarting

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am using XCode4 to write a simple Mac app and my breakpoint only works once until i restart XCode.
After a fresh start of XCode4 build and run triggers the breakpoint again as expected.

But if i then stop the app and build and run again it doesnt stop at the very same breakpoint. It continues execution just as if there was no breakpoint. After restarting XCode it works again. But only one time.

So the question is: What can be done to make it work without restarting XCode4.

Comment: FWIW, Xcode 4.1 is the current version.

Comment: But is 4.1 not running only on Lion ?

Comment: I think you're right.  I'm already on Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the (simple) solution:

Even though the "Breakpoints"-Button in the toolbar was already active - deactivating and activating it again did the trick. After doing this i tested it about 4-5 times and it now works without restarting. Even after restarting XCode4 without re-activating Breakpoints it again.

Also: I am using XCode 4.0 at the moment. Maybe this is just a rare problem and perhaps it was fixed in 4.0.1 / 4.0.2 and does not happen anymore.

Anyway, should have tried this before writing the question ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me in Xcode 4.3.2.  Only thing that seems to work is re-running repeatedly until I see the breakpoints getting set in the gdb console output.